# How to change the look and feel of the newsletter subscription form

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, newsletter

I'm looking to change the style and font size of the form used subscribe for e-mail newsletters.

Right now the form is shown in a table form with small font size which is not suitable for mobile users.

I'm using this code to get the form shown in the CMS:
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}

I'm thinking that i need to edit the subscribe.phtml file but how to do this.

My shop is on version 1.7.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Magento theme fallback to style e-mail subscription form.

Copy file subscribe.phtml from app/design/frontend/base/default/newsletter/ to app/design/[your package]/[your theme]/default/newsletter/

You can edit this copied file to customise your subscription form.

P.S. [your package] and [your theme] can be found in Magento backend at system -> configuration -> design